# Why teamviewer starts again after being killed

Tags: process, kill, teamviewer

My main desktop has Mint 14 and I approached it via SSH from another computer, because I didn't have a screen on the Mint one. Then I tried to start teamviewer just I order to launch its desktop session remotely. I started the teamviewer and everything ran fine, but then I tried to stop this application from the terminal and this is what happens:

#### Checking:

```
x@x-pc /opt/teamviewer8 $ ps -ef | grep team
root      1567     1  0 20:55 ?        00:00:00 /opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/teamviewerd -f
x         2892     1  0 21:41 ?        00:00:00 /opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/wine/bin/wineserver
x         2914  2822  0 21:48 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto team
```

#### Using one-liner just to feel myself more hacker like :)

```
sudo for i in `ps -ef | grep team | awk {'print $2'} | xargs`; do kill -9 $i; done
```

#### Checking again:

```
x-pc teamviewer8 # ps -ef | grep team
root      3003     1  0 21:50 ?        00:00:00 /opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/teamviewerd -f
root      3009  2957  0 21:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto team
```

#### Killing again:

```
x-pc teamviewer8 # ps -ef | grep team
root      3003     1  0 21:50 ?        00:00:00 /opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/teamviewerd -f
root      3011  2957  0 21:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto team
x-pc teamviewer8 #
x-pc teamviewer8 #
x-pc teamviewer8 #
x-pc teamviewer8 #
x-pc teamviewer8 # kill -9 3003
x-pc teamviewer8 #
x-pc teamviewer8 #
x-pc teamviewer8 # ps -ef | grep team
root      3012     1  2 21:57 ?        00:00:00 /opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/teamviewerd -f
root      3017  2957  0 21:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto team
#########################################
```

No matter how many times I killed it, it receives new PID. How can I kill it?

Comment: (For your one-liner: look into `pgrep`/`pkill`)

Comment: Try `killall -9 teamviewer`. If doesn't work please show the output of `pstree`.

Answer (score 16):

If you do

```
teamviewer --daemon stop
```

you stop it once but it starts again upon next boot, but with

```
sudo update-rc.d teamviewerd remove
```

you also prevent it from starting itself on bootup

Answer (score 6):

Try to stop systemd service (if you use systemd):

```
# systemctl stop teamviewerd
# systemctl disable teamviewerd
```

Comment: No, actually I do not use it.

Comment: these works on centos 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
# teamviewer --daemon stop
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable Teamviewer on startup :

```
teamviewer --daemon disable
```

Comment: this disables starting the daemon _at the next startup_. the question was how to kill it.

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 16.04, It first stops the daemon, then disables it so it doesn't restart at the next boot. You need to use `sudo` if you are not root.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 12.04, but I do not think the process will be different using other versions of Ubuntu.

TeamViewer screen sharing is my choice to replace the "TOO BLURRED TO READ" Skype screen share. The window sizes are about the same on my screen, but I can now read the print whereas the Skype blur makes reading impossible.

Please note that although TeamViewer runs under Wine, there are many native scripts that also run.

There has been some notice of the "TeamViewer remote control daemon" (teamviewerd) remaining active after the user is finished using and terminated TeamViewer. Respawning is also used to make sure it stays active. 
The easiest solution is to reboot or logout after making sure the "start with system" check box is cleared. When you log in, TeamViewer should not start and the daemon should not appear.

If you want a solution that does not require logging out, you must delete the respawn commands from the configuration file.

In the terminal, enter:

```
gksudo gedit -s /etc/init/teamviewerd.conf
```

Delete the two lines:

```
respawn

respawn limit 5 60
```

Save the file. Do not worry about the teamviewerd.conf.bak file.

Now that respawn is disabled, ending the daemon will end it. I did not notice anything unusual in the way TeamViewer functions with the modified script.

Note: the changes will not initially take effect until TeamViewer reads the script. Reboot, log-out, or terminate and restart TeamViewer are options. I only tried log-out and it worked for me. I did not try the other options as I modified the script only once.